# Rigidbody 2D doesn't stop

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies, prefab

In my scene I am instantiating at runtime a prefab, which has a dynamic Rigidbody2D and a BoxCollider2D;
It also has a script with an OnTriggerEnter2D method, that runs the following function:

```
/* ... */
public Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

private void StopMovement()
{
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    Debug.Log(rigidbody.velocity);
}
```

Basically I want the object to stop when he collides with the trigger. The problem is it doesn't stop, and even if the console message says `(0.0, 0.0)` the rigidbody's inspector looks like this:

[image]

And as you can see, its velocity isn't actually zero.
I tried adding

```
rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezeAll;
```

but all it does is freezing the position **on the prefab**, not on the actual gameObject instance. And I don't get how that's possible, also considering that the Rigidbody field on the script is occupied by `Ball(clone)`, which is the name of the gameObject that's in the scene.
I also tried using `GetComponent` in Awake/Start instead of there, but the result was the same.

I've already looked up a bunch of other posts, both here and on UnityAnswers, but none of them could help me. What is happening exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after when I read this "but all it does is freezing the position on the prefab, not on the actual gameObject instance". What exactly are you after when you say the ball should stop when it hits the trigger?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. I have a gameObject that moves in my scene, and I want it to stop moving, that's it. What actually happens is that the script targets the prefab file (the one that exists in the project, not the scene) and not the object that is in the scene. See those tickboxes under the `Constraints` dropdown? When the function runs, they change in the prefab but not on the scene object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that what caused that strange behaviour was related to a custom Event System, that's why it has taken so long to figure out.
Basically I was assigning the prefab as the target object in the Event Listener's inspector, thinking that its effect would be automatically applied to all the instances of that prefab, but in the end it doesn't work like that.
If anyone has the same issue, I solved it by putting the Event Listener component onto the vary target object, so basically it references itself and causes the expected behaviour.

[image]

Thanks for everyone's time, this can be closed now.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the prefab and not the actual gameObjecy and so the rigidbody. When you instantiate the ball use a

'GameObject ballClone = Instantiate(ballpref, pos, quaternion);'

In this way you can access to ballClone.getcomponent() and it will work fine

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time. Yes, your solution does work, but I still don't understand why mine doesn't. You're saying that there is no way to affect a prefab instance at runtime unless it is saved in a field immediately after instantiating? Shouldn't prefabs work like normal gameObjects after they're instantiated?

Comment: No, because if you use a public GameObjecy and you drag inside it a prefab, you will simply control that prefab. The prefab it's just an object like others but when you instantiate you are cloning it, but if you call the variable you instantiated you are accessing the prefab itself. Was I useful?

Comment: I thought that by assigning a prefab to an Inspector field then it would automatically target all the future instances that would be created from that prefab. I had already figured out that it isn't the case, but thanks anyway!

Comment: No but you can find every object instantiated and every clone if you put a Tag and use GameObject[] copies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(); upvote if you want :)

Comment: Thank you for your comments and your time but I already found a solution that doesn't involve finding references at runtime, as you can see by my own answer to this question :)